# QuickMapServices It is not for ubuntu?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, google-maps

I'm new using QGis. I read somewhere that QMS was better and more stable than the OpenLayers complement to use Google Maps. My problem is that it does not appear when I search with the plugins administrator. I use Ubuntu 14.04 and Qgis 2.0.

regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QMS is certainly installable using Ubuntu 14.04 and QGIS 2.14.1 so I suspect your issue is the age of your QGIS install if it really is 2.0.

Comment: Yes, I installed through software center. I'll find a way to install a newer version. Maybe the problem is there. Thank you

Comment: see https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html for details

Comment: Yes, I update my version and everything works. Thank you!